# Tiva C TM4C123GXL Interface Library

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m, cmsis

I am currently taking an online class, UT.6.02x Embedded Systems - Shape the World, that uses the Tiva C TM4C123GXL LaunchPad. I am also reading the book "The Definitive Guide to ARM Cortex-M3 And Cortex-M4 Processors" to complement. In the book a standard library called CMSIS is mentioned, where the GPIO ports' registers are implemented as a structure.

**Book code:**

```
typedef struct
{
_IO uint32_t CRL;
_IO uint32_t CRH;
//and so on ...
} GPIO_TypeDef;

#define PERIPH_BASE ((uint32_t)0x40000000) //Peripheral base address
#define APB2PERIPH_BASE (PERIPH_BASE + 0x10000)
#define GPIOA_BASE (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x0800)
#define GPIOA ((GPIO_TypeDef*) GPIOA_BASE)
```

where _IO is defined as volatile.

If I wanted to set GPIOA  CRL register to 0, I could type GPIOA->CRL = 0;
And I could also call functions such as GPIO_Reset(GPIOA).

For the class, the professor is not using this library, instead he includes a header file [*tm4c123gh6pm.h*](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/Volume1/tm4c123gh6pm.h), which defines each register for every port separately:

**Class code:**

```
#define GPIO_PORTA_DATA_BITS_R  ((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004000)
#define GPIO_PORTA_DATA_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x400043FC))
#define GPIO_PORTA_DIR_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004400))
#define GPIO_PORTA_IS_R         (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004404))
#define GPIO_PORTA_IBE_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004408))
#define GPIO_PORTA_IEV_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x4000440C))
#define GPIO_PORTA_IM_R         (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004410))
#define GPIO_PORTA_RIS_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004414))
#define GPIO_PORTA_MIS_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004418))
#define GPIO_PORTA_ICR_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x4000441C))
#define GPIO_PORTA_AFSEL_R      (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004420))
#define GPIO_PORTA_DR2R_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004500))
#define GPIO_PORTA_DR4R_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004504))
#define GPIO_PORTA_DR8R_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004508))
#define GPIO_PORTA_ODR_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x4000450C))
#define GPIO_PORTA_PUR_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004510))
#define GPIO_PORTA_PDR_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004514))
#define GPIO_PORTA_SLR_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004518))
#define GPIO_PORTA_DEN_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x4000451C))
#define GPIO_PORTA_LOCK_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004520))
#define GPIO_PORTA_CR_R         (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004524))
#define GPIO_PORTA_AMSEL_R      (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004528))
#define GPIO_PORTA_PCTL_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x4000452C))
#define GPIO_PORTA_ADCCTL_R     (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004530))
#define GPIO_PORTA_DMACTL_R     (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004534))
```

which seems to make registers manipulation more troublesome.

Is this header file used anywhere else other than this class? Is it considered part of the CMSIS?

What is the difference between both files?

Comment: Your professor is the best person to answer questions about the course material. He may have some specific reason for using this header file that relates to some concept he will cover during the course. He may simply prefer it because _he_ finds it more convenient - ask him.

Comment: The difference is that they're different, in pretty much exactly the ways you spell out - one is an an example of how a vendor might define a CMSIS-style structure for an example GPIO controller, the other is (if you look at the top of the file) some actual register definitions taken from a particular vendor's SDK for a particular SoC. [CMSIS is just a recommended standard abstraction layer](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-m/cortex-microcontroller-software-interface-standard.php), vendors are free to choose to implement it or not.

Comment: Also, from the user perspective, the difference in this case mostly boils down to occasionally typing `_` instead of `->` in names to access registers - does that _really_ matter?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: the GPIO hardware in your chip is **designed by TI instead of ARM** and thus its headers have a slightly different coding style.

## Longer Explanation

When using Cortex-M microcontrollers, it's helpful to keep track of which part of the hardware were designed by ARM and which were designed by the silicon vendor that licensed the processor from ARM (TI in this case). ARM designed the CPU and the debug and tracing related hardware blocks (that you could even use to do some I/O, e.g. SWD) but everything else, GPIO, Timers, PWM, ADC, UART, SPI, I2S are all done by silicon vendor. Thus, even a simple low-level `blink` example would not port from TI to ST, NXP or Atmel chips even if they're all Cortex-M microcontrollers.

ARM had a CMSIS-Driver initiative that was aimed at creating a unified API for the common peripherals, but it's essentially dead. For portable high-level APIs, look to the [mBed](https://mbed.org/) or [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) projects.

Answer (score 1):

The file used in that class is not considered part of CMSIS. If you'll like to know how to set up an environment to create CMSIS compliant software take a look at this short tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQZi81O3cMc&list=PLmfT_cdP5PYBWYvK_bCdGyBqQEiRzUPeq&index=11

Answer (score -1):

actually the file is from Texas Instruments avalible with the TivaWare Bundle

http://www.ti.com/tool/SW-TM4C

Comment: This sdk does not include the required files.